# Is there any resource that explains everything about the PUT, POST, DELETE operation in WCF Data Services?

Tags: rest, wcf-data-services

Every single resource I'va come across on Internet always describes very well what you can do with the GET operation, how it works and so on, bu it never explains the POST/PUT/DELETE and particularly the format of the data you pass in the HTTP body (I'm using JSON). It always says "you can make a post request and pass the appropriate data in the body".

I am struggling with what I can do and not. For example I want to know if it is possible to update one field of one entry by just sending the updated value, and not the entire object.

Is there any document that explains clearly the possibilities and limitations?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to read documentation is here: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols

If you want all the dirty details and a strict language you can read this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541188(PROT.10).aspx

You can modify a value of a single property by sending a PUT request.
For example if you send a GET to this URL:

```
http://services.odata.org/(S(kupqbta5wqnfz2cln1qk052x))/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Name
```

And you request JSON (through an Accept header) the response will be:

```
{
"d" : {
"Name": "Bread"
}
}
```

The "d" wrapper is there only to avoid XSS attacks so that must not be included in the requests, but the rest stays the same, so if you then send a PUT request like this:

```
PUT http://services.odata.org/(S(kupqbta5wqnfz2cln1qk052x))/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Name HTTP/1.1
Host: services.odata.org
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20

{
"Name": "Meat"
}
```

It will update the property Name to value Meat. You can also send a PUT to the value itself, in which case the URL would end with $value (denotes the raw value of the property) like this:

```
PUT http://services.odata.org/(S(kupqbta5wqnfz2cln1qk052x))/OData/OData.svc/Products(0)/Name/$value HTTP/1.1
Host: services.odata.org
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 4

Meat
```

Note that this only works on primitive properties though.
The sample service on the odata.org allows you to make modifications (guarded by the session key in the URL), so can play with it there.

Answer (score 0):

Google for the HTTP 1.1 specification.